# Unable to use LocateOnScreen function on Pyautogui (Python 3.9)

Tags: pyautogui, python-3.9

Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui
cord = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('chrome.png')
    pyautogui.doubleClick(cord)'
```

However, I got this error:
[image: The Pillow package is required to use this function.]

I installed Pillow and imported PIL

I also installed opencv and numpy.

Through some research I realised it could be some site-package issues/ environment issues. I uninstalled and reinstalled python and updated the PATH.

please help I am at my wits end.

Answer (score 0):

Known problem - i had it too. Maybe downgrade to 3.8 OR even 3.7.
I had to downgrade to 3.7 because a module in pyautoGUI made my script crash.